# Reversing linked list using stack?

Tags: java

This is a code that reverses linked list using stack. I got everything right from creating a linked list and getting input from the user, but I got some logic wrong. Iam trying to reverse linked list using stack, but it is only reversing two number if say suppose I give in three numbers. How do I get it right?

import java.util.*;

```
class LinkedList{
    Node head;
    
    static class Node{`
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d){
            this.data = d;
            next = null;
        }
    }
    
    public static LinkedList insert(LinkedList list, int data){
        Node new_node = new Node(data);
        if(list.head == null){
            list.head = new_node;
        }
        else{
            Node last = list.head;
            while(last.next != null){
                last = last.next;
            }
            last.next = new_node;
        }
        
        return list;
    }
    
    public static LinkedList reverse(LinkedList list){
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        Node current = list.head;
        while(current.next != null){
            stack.push(current.data);
            current = current.next;
        }
        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("The reversed list is: " + stack.pop());
        }
        return list;
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList l = new LinkedList();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int length = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=length; i++){
            int number = sc.nextInt();
            l.insert(l,number);
        }
        l.reverse(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: change `current.next` to `current`

Comment: Yeah! that worked.

Comment: Happy to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your reverse function. While reading the linked list your while loop logic is skipping the last item.

Correct function is:

```
public static LinkedList reverse(LinkedList list){
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    Node current = list.head;
    while(current != null){  // instead of while(current.next != null)
        System.out.println("Pushed Data:"+current.data);
        stack.push(current.data);
        current = current.next;
    }
   System.out.println("The reversed list is: ");
    while(!stack.isEmpty()){
        
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good except the line `while(current.next != null){` as here you check for the next node instead of the current node. So you need to change this line to `while(current != null){`